# My Web View in android only showing the html Code can Any suggest me what to do to see the Real Web page

Tags: android, webview

My Web View in android only showing the `html Code` can Any suggest me what to do to see the Real Web page..

My Code is Here

```
WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/");
   // mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/");
mWebView.loadData("http://news.yahoo.com/rss","TEXT/HTML", "UTF-8");
Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);

private  class  HelloWebViewClient  extends  WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public  boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.getBackground();
        return  true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the address gives only access to the RSS feed of yahoo news.

Rss is in fact an XML file with no style information: http://wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

The best way to do it is to download the xml file, parse it and display it with Textviews..

To parse it you can use Saxx parser.

This page should help you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/